# The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: 2007

I'm trying to make a console application that updates a Sharepoint list as a scheduled task. For some reason when I try to build the console app, I get the following error message.

"The type or namespace name 'SharePoint' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

However, I have added Micorosft.Sharepoint.dll, and I can see it in my references folder. I have also copied and pasted the dll to a different directory and referenced that one incase there was an access issue.

I've written webparts using WSPBuilder before without a problem. Any idea what could be causing this?

sharepoint 2007, visual studio 2010

Comment: Are you running this console application on the server itself?

Comment: Yes, I'm on the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas:

1) Try Clean Solution from the solution context menu.

2) Make sure that your projects are targeting .NET 3.5 (not 4.0 client profile)

3) Make sure your build is configured to target "Any CPU"

Comment: Perfect, I forgot to change the target to .net 3.5. Thanks.